# Classification: Layer error: Property 'Class' of feature '2_0_0' is missing:

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification

When I was trying for LU classification, I am getting an error:

> Classification: Layer error: Property 'Class' of feature '2_0_0' is
> missing.

What is the reason for this error and the solution?

```
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")

var image = L8.filterBounds(ROI)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 1)
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-12-31')
  .median()
  .clip(ROI)
  
print(image)
Map.addLayer(image, imageVisParam, 'Ture_color_composite')
Map.centerObject(ROI, 10)

var training = Water.merge(Built_Up).merge(Vegetation).merge(Forest).merge(Wasteland)
print(training)

var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7']
var train_image = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: training,
  properties: ['Class'],
  scale: 30

})

print(train_image)
//train classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
  features: train_image,
  classProperty: 'Class',
  inputProperties: bands,
})
//run classification
var classified = image.select(bands).classify(classifier)

Map.centerObject(training, 11)
var landcoverPalette = ['#0c2c84', '#e31a1c', '#005a32', '#FF8000', '#969696']
Map.addLayer(classified, {palette: landcoverPalette, min: 0, max: 4}, 'Classification')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have left out the definition of your reference data, `Water`, `Built_Up`, `Vegetation`, `Forest`, and `Wasteland`. I believe your problem is with them. - they're probably missing a `Class` property. I added some dummy reference data with the `Class` property, and your script runs just fine.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e92ba6af4ab55ae377758f2021e97cb1

Comment: Thanksfor your response. Even I added the properties it was not added. With your suggestion I created the layers again and then the code ran.